# Coldfusion JRUN 4 Server - how to stop it

Tags: coldfusion, jrun

I got halfway through installing a security patch for CF801 ent (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/890/cpsid_89094.html) on a windows 2k8 server + iis.

I made a backup copy of the WEB-INF directory as instructed. Then I tried to merge the new WEB-INF provided by Adobe. It hung up on one particular file (C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\lib\cfmx_bootstrap.jar), with the error:

```
Cannot delete output file (above file).
```

So, I tried renaming the file and got the error:

```
The action can't be completed because the file is open in jrun.exe.
```

I have stopped the server via JRUN launcher, so where could the file still be open. I tried rebooting the server in case there was something still running in the background. Error persists.

I'm new to enterprise multiserver installs, so I may be missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: Stopping the server instance via JRUN Launcher doesn't shut the coldfusion server. I needed to stop it in services, which I tried originally, but I wasn't used to the way CF with JRUN was appearing in the services (It appears as "Macromedia JRUN CFusion Server", whereas I had been looking for services beginning with "ColdFusion" or "Adobe"). Once I found the service and stopped it, I was able to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I would try setting all the ColdFusion services to start manually instead of automatically, and reboot.  Install the security pack, set the services back to start automatically, and reboot again.

HTH.